# how to change the value of DOM elements in v8

Tags: dom, v8

I am trying to change the _nodeValue of HeapObjects directly in the method SetPropertyForResult in object.cc file. (replacing the value by encrypted one).
After I change, I check the _noveValue and I see the change is applied to the object. But surprisingly, I see the old value when it is assigned to a variable.

Is the any shadow of objects in v8? OR the _nodeValue is not the place I have to change? OR SetPropertyForResult is not the correct place. Maybe I have to go to method Store in ic.cc.

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Why don't you add an interceptor to the ObjectTemplates for the DOM objects, if you're modifying Chromium anyways?
This way you could observe access to any named properties and also set handlers for read and write access separately. And I would expect that this way there are no surprising things like you observed.

Comment: Thank you for reply. You are right that we can manage to do this in the browser where DOM and binding happens. In our design, however, we have tried to minimize the trusted code (We just want to trust v8, not other components of the browser including parser, DOM, ...). We could do it at the points that v8 wants to connect to DOM, but inside v8. More precisely, we do it in GetPropertyWithCallBack and SetPropertyWithCallBack, then we had no problem.